# Why can't I println "left" when left arrow is pressed?

Tags: javafx

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.println("handle");
                if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.LEFT)) {
                    System.out.println("left");
                }
            }


        };

        Circle circle = new Circle(200,200,100);
        circle.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);
        circle.setOnKeyPressed(eventHandler);

        root.getChildren().add(circle);


        stage.setTitle("JavaFX GUI");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Why can't I println "left" when left arrow is pressed ? I don't understand... It is a JavaFX Application...
I want that when I type left arrow in my keyboard, this prinln "left"

Comment: Is "handle" printed out?

Comment: Before you keep asking new questions start replying to and "accepting" answers in your old questions!

Answer (score 1):

You added the listener to a `Node` that doesn't receive the focus. Add it to the `Scene` instead:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(eventHandler);
```

or set the [`focusTraversable` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty) of the `Circle` to `true`:

```
circle.setFocusTraversable(true);
```